# Bootstrap Using Row & Col with Angular List Ordering

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Is there a way in bootstrap & angular to have a list split into columns like this, notice it puts the first 4 entries into first column, before populating the second column.

```
a     e
b     f
c     g
d     h
```

Here is my example code which doesn't put them in the desired order:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let item of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Which outputs like this, you can see the order of the letters isn't correct, it's doing it row by row:

```
a     b
c     d
e     f
g     h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the for loop on the columns, you want just **two** columns.

So, you want the for loop on whats **inside** the column, and in the *first* column you want the first half the list (`i <= items.length / 2`)

and

in the *second* column you want the second half the list (`i > items.length / 2`)

```
let items: Array<string> = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <span *ngIf="i < items.length/2">{{ item }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
                <span *ngIf="i >= items.length/2">{{ item }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Update - Responsive

## [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zueEo2Bdyx91Q6mRMahg?p=preview)

**Html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Any media less than 300px screen width will shrink into a 1 column list  */

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  ul {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  ul {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you :)
Any idea how I could make it responsive as well, so on a smaller device I'd want 2 columns col-6 and on larger ones I'd want to use col-4 for 3 columns?

Comment: Sure no problem glad to help out. Yeah give me a moment to update my answer

Comment: @Smartie So that one is a thinker but I'm working on it yet

Comment: @Smartie I believe I have your responsive answer, check the updated answer. I even posted a demo of it working on Plunker and linked it in my answer. One con is that is a css solution rather than using bootstrap's grid system

Comment: Feel free to tweak the media queries min length to best fit your needs

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed, I've used media-breakpoint-only(md) etc.. with it, instead of exact sizes :)

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be very hard to split up the array responsively. A simpler approach is to use the Bootstrap 4 `card-columns` instead of the grid columns. This will order the data top-to-bottom and split up into columns. Then you just need a CSS media query to have 3 columns instead of 2 on larger screens.

```
<div class="card-columns">
     <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
         {{$index+1}} {{ item.name }}
     </div>    
</div>

.card-columns {
    column-count: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/3UBWN6Hc3k

Answer (score -1):

```
let listItems: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g'];

<div class="row">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i < listItems.length/2" class="col-6">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="i >= listItems.length/2" class="col-6">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same output as the example I have given, which isn't in the order desired.

Comment: You edited what you had there before? Why change your question then tell me im wrong?

Comment: You did not have any modulus operator in your ealier code, also you were using an array in your ngFor loop

Comment: Read the edit history, I've only changed the wording to try and explain my issue better, the underlying question is the same. Thank you for trying to help me though :)

Comment: Ive updated the answer this should work, i misread what you wanted

Comment: Thanks again, but this is still outputting in the wrong order, if you look at the accepted answer, I think you were almost there, but needed to loop twice!